# How to get document.currentscript from within script and pointing parentNode

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the user scrolls the page, I'm going to append one div tag and append one js tag within the same div.

Now, I am pointing to the parent tag with 'js_div_1','js_div_2', 'js_div_3' etc... , and appending some stuff.

Html form :

```
<div id="divider" class="long">
        <!-- Firt iteration - when document ready-->
        <div id="js_div_1" >
            <script async="" id="js_file_1" type="text/javascript" src="sample.js"></script>
        </div>

</div>
```

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var divCounter = 0;
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.scrollHeight) {
      // you're at the bottom of the page
        console.log("Reached bottom and load more content here");
        divCounter++;


        var slotDiv     = document.createElement('div');
        slotDiv.id  = 'js_div_'+divCounter; // Id must be the same as slotName
        $('#divider').append(slotDiv);

        var adScript    = document.createElement('script');
        adScript.async  = true; 
        adScript.id     = "js_file_"+divCounter;
        adScript.type   = 'text/javascript';
        adScript.src    = "sample.js";
        $('#js_div_'+divCounter).append(adScript);  
    }
});
```

Inside the **sample.js** file content:

```
console.log(document.currentScript);    
var parentTag = document.currentScript;
parentTag.parentNode.removeChild(parentTag );   
parentTag.parentNode.appendChild('Success');
```

Actual output:(console.log)

```
<script>
console.log(document.currentScript);    
var parentTag = document.currentScript;
parentTag.parentNode.removeChild(parentTag );
parentTag.parentNode.appendChild('Success');    
</script>
```

Expected output: (Need to point to parentNode div 'js_div_1' and append response)

```
 <div id="divider" class="long">
        <!-- 1st iteration - when document ready-->
        <div id="js_div_1" >
            Success
        </div>

       <!-- 2nd iteration - when document ready-->
        <div id="js_div_1" >
            Success
        </div>
       <!-- 3nd iteration -->
        etc...
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you try: new URL(document.currentScript.src).origin

Answer (score 1):

To be able to make a faster javascript code, you have to change a little bit your Html:

Html code:

```
<div id="divider" class="long">
    <!-- Firt iteration - when document ready-->
    <div id="js_div_1" class="js-div-container" data-iteration="1" >
        <script async="" id="js_file_1" class="js-link" type="text/javascript" src="sample.js"></script>
    </div>

</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollHeight = $(document).height();
    var scrollPosition = $(this).height() + $(this).scrollTop();

    if ((scrollHeight - scrollPosition) / scrollHeight === 0) {
           // when scroll to bottom of the page
           var el = $('.js-div-container:last-child');
           var iteration = parseInt(el.attr("data-iteration")) + 1;

           el.clone().attr({'id': 'js_div_' + iteration, 'data-iteration': iteration}).appendTo('#divider');

           el.find('.js-link').attr('id', 'js_file_' + iteration);
       }
    });
});
```

These code will output the expected result. But I don't understand Why and What is this script sample.js have to be loaded multiple times?